# Flutter ARCore Plugin onNodeTap and onPlaneTap don't work

Tags: flutter, arcore

I have a basic AR app with Fluttern, using the `arcore_flutter_plugin` plugin, which I made following some tutorials. I am trying to do some actions when the `arCoreController.onNodeTap` and `onPlaneTap` are triggered. But it doesn't seem to work. The code shows no errors, but nothing happens when I tap the node or the plane.

```
  void _onArCoreViewCreated(ArCoreController controller) {
    arCoreController = controller;
    arCoreController.onPlaneTap = _onPlaneTap;
    arCoreController.onNodeTap= handleTap;
  }

  _onPlaneTap(List<ArCoreHitTestResult> hits) => _onHitDetected(hits.first);
  void handleTap(String name){
    print('Node Tapped');
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          AlertDialog(content: Text('onNodeTap on $name')),
    );
  }
  void _onHitDetected(ArCoreHitTestResult plane){
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          AlertDialog(content: Text('On Plane Tap done')),
    );
  }
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `enableTapRecognizer` to `true`.

For example:

```dart
body: ArCoreView(
  enableTapRecognizer: true,
  onArCoreViewCreated: _onArCoreViewCreated,
)
```